# Evaluate function not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, spreadsheet

[image]

In the example, entering the combined values in K2 as a formula produces the result in J2.  J2 is value copied and pasted in J4.  To confirm that it is a formula that will not produce an error, the text of J4 is copied and entered as a formula in J6 (which does produce the proper result).  It was believed the EVALUATE function would take care of all these steps so you could just combine the formula in K2 with EVALUATE, and it would produce the result in J6 (and H2).  However, when that combination is tried in J8, it gives an error message. Is there something in the J8 formula (shown in K8) that is not being entered properly?  Is there a way for excel to evaluate the formula in K2 and get the same result as J6?

Comment: Evaluate is either a named function in the name manager or it is a udf.  Can you show how evaluate is defined or the code that is being used?  EVALUATE is not a native function in Excel.

Comment: But you are missing a `)` in your formula string.

Comment: Note: even though not indicated, the K8 formula was also entered as an array (ctrl-shift-enter)

Comment: If you have Filter in Excel, then the Array entry (ctrl-shift-enter) is not needed.  Are you using Excel?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you should not tag with a program that you are not using.  Any Answer you get for Excel will not translate over to WPF.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you shouldn't assume.  I am using Excel.  Are you here to help or troll?  If to help, what is the way to evaluate the K2 formula -in Excel- to get the same result as J6?

Comment: In Excel, the only way to evaluate a string is to use vba.  There is an old work around using the name manager.  You did not answer my first question.  Also note that FILTER does not require the use of ctrl-shift-enter in Excel.  So please show how you defined the name EVALUATE or show the UDF that you call with EVALUATE.

Comment: Answering that first question, defining the name EVALUATE, or showing the UDF called won't help.  That's because, although I am currently using Excel, I formerly used WPF.  So I was trying to use the same functions as WPF.  Now that I know EVALUATE does not work in Excel, I will try the proper Excel solution if it is offered.

Comment: Where is the ) missing in the string?

Comment: At the end, there should be 2.

Comment: `=FILTER(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($F$1+1,B2:B700)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH($F$2+1,B2:B700)+1),(INDEX(B:B,MATCH($F$1+1,B2:B700)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH($F$2+1,B2:B700)+1)>=$F$1)*(INDEX(C:C,MATCH($F$1+1,B2:B700)):INDEX(C:C,MATCH($F$2+1,B2:B700)+1)=$C$1))`

Comment: Beautiful.  That fixed the problem in Excel and WPF.  Simple solution but I missed it.  How do I give you credit?  Can't find the "answered" button.

Comment: You cannot accept the comment as an answer..